# How to: Centralize and aggregate perf counter data

Tags: performancecounter, perfmon

We have several Windows servers in our production environment. We run IIS-based services on them. We have performance issues but little data to explain why. We want to add perf counters to critical parts of the code, and then be able to aggregate it in a single SQL DB for some simple analysis. I've started writing the following tools:

1. File watcher to copy .etl files to a central server from each prod box
2. File watcher on central server to load the .etl file data and then do a bulk insert into SQL
3. SQL DB with tables and views for analyzing the data

Then I got to thinking, someone must have built this before. Is there anything already existing out there that does this? Anything free or cheap?